# opening a modal for each item in a for loop separately

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I am displaying about 5 panels in which are rendered from an array and then displayed each panel with its own id, name and content to share. Within each panel i have an expand icon where i am allowing the user to expand the selected panel into a large modal. I am using the example from bootstrap but currently when i click to open in a modal - it opens in large modal but it opens for each item in the array and not just the selected panel. Here is what i have so far:

```
 <div class="col-sm-4" *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
         <div class="panel panel-warning">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                {{item.title}}
               <div class="box-header-btns pull-right">
                  <a title="Expand" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">
                      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-full"></i>
                  </a>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class="panel-body modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
                 <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                      <div class="modal-content">
                           {{item.content}}
                      </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
  </div>
```

My array to loop to display panels:

```
 items: Array<Panel> = [
        new Panel(1, 'panel 1', 'show text', 'test data in modal'),
        new Panel(2, 'panel 2','show image', 'more test data'),
        new Panel(3, 'panel 3', 'show graph', 'more and more data')
    ];

class Panel {
  constructor(
    public id: number, 
    public title: string, 
    public footer: string, 
    public content: any) 
}
```

Currently when i open up a modal for an  item it also loops through all the other items before the modal closes out.

Comment: What does your expandPanel() method look like?

Comment: Please reduce indentation, it is difficult to read

Comment: also post your modal HTML part please, also according to me you need to provide `data-target` dynamically

Comment: Actually, I think the issue here is that you are creating a distinct modal dialog for _each_ iteration of the `ngFor`

Comment: @aluanHaddad I went a head and added more code hopefully it will help. I could see how the ngFor is causing for the modal to loop but not sure how to separate yet work properly .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic plunkr (extremely ugly) with working code.
https://plnkr.co/edit/lISLyUaMbc1W28sWRugi?p=info

As I said earlier, the issue here is that you are creating a distinct modal dialog for each iteration of the loop. However, since you forgot to include your function that selects an item, its almost impossible to say what was actually wrong

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `

<div class="col-sm-4" *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
  <div class="panel panel-warning">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <div class="box-header-btns pull-right" (click)="selectedItem = item">
        <a title="Expand" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-full"></i> {{item.title}}
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-body modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      {{selectedItem?.content}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<pre>{{selectedItem && selectItem.content | json}}</pre>
  `
})
export class App {
  items = [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'panel 1',
    footer: 'show text',
    content: 'test data in modal'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    title: 'panel 2',
    footer: 'show image',
    content: 'more test data'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    title: 'panel 3',
    footer: 'show graph',
    content 'more and more data'
  }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am giving it a try now. i didn't really get `<pre>{{selectedItem && selectItem.content | json}}</pre>` is that more for testing the data display?

Comment: exactly just for debugging output in a pinch, otherwise use Augery or something.

Comment: This worked perfectly - Thank you for your help!! I may have another question dealing with the same code but i will create a separate question for that and hopefully you will be able to help out as well.

Comment: @bluePearl You may want to look into using ng-bootstrap or some other higher level, angular oriented library, it will save you lots of time. Glad I was able to be of assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happened is that when the array is rendered they  all have the same class, to solve that you will use variable id for the trigger button,
in python-django you can solve that by getting the unique number of each list

set the id has something like

```
id ='button-{{forloop.counter}}' , and in javascript it's
```

```
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].id = `button-${i}`;}
```

You can also add your modal function to this likewise in your script

So basically set variable id in your Html Template and your Script

Answer (score -1):

The content should be loaded in childcomponent for Example see the below code In That expandPanel you can add a param and try to use this

```
<div class="col-sm-4" *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
            <div class="panel panel-warning">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    {{item.title}}
                    <div class="box-header-btns pull-right">
                        <a title="Expand" (click)="expandPanel(i);" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-full"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document" *ngFor="let children of item.children">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            {{children.content}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And the json file should like this

```
this.items= [
            {
                titile: "xxxxx",  children: [
                    { content: 'aaaaa'},
                   { content: 'bbbbbb'},
                  { content: 'cccccc'}
                ]
            },
            {
                title: "zzzzzz", children: [
                    { content: 'gggggg'},
                   { content: 'jjjjjjjjjj'}
                ]
            },
            {
                title: "ddddd", children: [
                    { content: 'ppppp'}
                ]
            }
        ];



 expandPanel(index: number) {
        this.items[index].active = !this.items[index].active;
        this.collapseAnother(index);
    }

collapseAnother(index: number) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
            if (i != index) {
                this.items[i].active = false;
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: That doesn't event make sense.

Comment: I tried this and i ended up with the same problem when i open a modal it loops through all items before closing.

Comment: I am using bootstrap so it takes care of some of the functionality like closing and opening so i don't have to configure that - I know i had expandPanel in my div but i forgot to remove it because i was no longer using it. I will give this a try and see if it works how i wanted it and use it for future reference. Thanks